# Why is there no $u$-channel in $A_1 + A_2 \rightarrow A_1 + A_2$ scattering?

Tags: particle-physics

Two particle species $A_1$ and $A_2$ with respective masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ scatter in a process of the type $A_1 + A_2 \rightarrow A_1 + A_2$. I am required to show that the matrix element $\mathcal{M}$ for this type of interaction cannot have a dependence on the Mandelstam variable $u$. I understand that this would require a process where the particles change their species after exchanging a virtual particle, but this does not necessarily break conservation of 4-momentum at any vertex of the Feynman diagram, so why is it not allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to interpret properly what you have in mind with this question but the u-channel of the reaction $A_1 + A_2 \to A_1 + A_2$ would correspond to the reaction: $A_1 + \bar{A_2} \to A_1 + \bar{A_2}$. Except if $A_2$ is its own anti-particle, the u-channel is different from the s-channel and thus you can't add both amplitudes.

I'm using the following convention: If the reaction $A_1 + A_2 \to A_3 + A_4$ is considered as the s-channel then 
$s=(p_1+p_2)^2 = (p_3+p_4)^2$, $t=(p_1-p_3)^2 = (p_4-p_2)^2$, $u=(p_1-p_4)^2 = (p_3-p_2)^2$ meaning that the t-channel reaction is $A_1 + \bar{A_3} \to \bar{A_2} + A_4$ and the u-channel reaction is $A_1 + \bar{A_4} \to A_3 + \bar{A_2}$.